# Crawling WoS with Python

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to download information from WoS (Web of Science) database. I need information such as name of article, authors, times cited, volume and others
[image]

This is my code:

```
import sys 
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
    var = raw_input("Link WoS: ")
    conn = urllib.urlopen(var)
    html = conn.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    titles = re.findall('<value lang_id="">(.+?)</value>',str(soup))
    volume = re.findall('Volume: </span><span class="data_bold"><value>(.+?)</value>', str(soup))
    print(volume)
```

It works perfect for obtaining titles. However I have problems getting the following info: volume, issue, pages, date (published) and times cited. This is the source of the webpage:

```
</span><span name="source_title_1" id="source_title_1">
<value>
<span class="hitHilite">EDUCATIONAL RESEARCH</span>
</value>
</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">Volume: </span><span     class="data_bold">
<value>35</value>
</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">Issue: </span><span  class="data_bold">
<value>1</value>
</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">Pages: </span><span class="data_bold">
<value>3-25</value>
</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">Published: </span><span class="data_bold">
<value>SPR 1993</value>
</span> 
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block" id="links_1">
<nobr><span id="links_openurl_1"></span> <span id="links_full_text_1">     </span> <span id="links_doc_del_1"></span> <span id="links_patent_1">    </span> </nobr>
</div>
<div class="search-action-item">
<span id="solo_full_text_1" class="solo_full_text"></span><a      name="full_text_1" id="full_text_1" title="Full Text" class="button2link     button-ft" href="javascript:;"><span id="full_text_1" name="full_text_1" title="Full Text" class="button2 button-ft">Full Text</span></a>
<div class="popup-full-text" id="full_text_1_menu">
<span id="full_text_1_links"></span>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">$("#full_text_1").hide();</script><span style="display: inline-block" class="button-abstract" id="ViewAbstract1_text"><a title="View Abstract" alt="View Abstract" onclick="return hide_show_abstract('1', 'http://images.webofknowledge.com/WOKRS523R4/images/spacer.gif', 'http://images.webofknowledge.com/WOKRS523R4/images/spacer.gif', 'View Abstract', 'Close Abstract');" href="javascript:;" class="button9"><img align="absmiddle" title="View Abstract" alt="View Abstract" src="http://images.webofknowledge.com/WOKRS523R4/images/spacer.gif" id="ViewAbstract1_img">View Abstract<nobr></nobr></a></span><span style="display: none" class="button-abstract" id="HideAbstract1_text"><a title="Close Abstract" alt="Close Abstract" onclick="return hide_show_abstract('1',  'http://images.webofknowledge.com/WOKRS523R4/images/spacer.gif', 'http://images.webofknowledge.com/WOKRS523R4/images/spacer.gif', 'View Abstract', 'Close Abstract');" href="javascript:;" class="button9"><img align="absmiddle" title="Close Abstract" alt="Close Abstract" src="http://images.webofknowledge.com/WOKRS523R4/images/spacer.gif" id="HideAbstract1_img">Close Abstract<nobr></nobr></a></span><span style="display: none" url="http://apps.webofknowledge.com/ViewAbstract.do?product=WOS&amp;search_mode=GeneralSearch&amp;viewType=ViewAbstract&amp;qid=5&amp;SID=W1tvVEGCvoimqQujw4V&amp;page=1&amp;doc=1" id="ViewAbstract_Span1">
<!----></span></div><div class="search-results-data">
<div class="search-results-data-cite">Times Cited: <a title="View all of the articles that cite this one" href="/CitingArticles.do?product=WOS&amp;SID=W1tvVEGCvoimqQujw4V&amp;search_mode=CitingArticles&amp;parentProduct=WOS&amp;parentQid=5&amp;parentDoc=1&amp;REFID=448550&amp;excludeEventConfig=ExcludeIfFromNonInterProduct">487</a>
<br>
```

I think that I have problems because the data is numeric... Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. What could be easy with HTML_Parser???

Comment: I dont see any problem with your regex. Problem is somethings else.

Comment: I don't have access to WoS. Would you please replace the image of the HTML in your question with the actual textual HTML for the page you want to scrape. Include all of the HTML that's used to present the items you want to recover, from title through 'Published' (or wherever you want scraping to end).

Comment: I already change the image from the source code of the website. Thank you all with your help!!!

Comment: I finally did it!!! I did this for all numeric values: numericValues= re.findall('<value>(.+?)</value>', str(soup)). Thank you all for your help!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup will do a lot of heavy lifting for you. Regex is usually a last resort where HTML is concerned. It's also best to use the most up-to-date version of this product, as seen in the following code.

```
HTML = '''\
<value>
<span class="htmllite">EDUCATIONAL RESEARCH</span>
</value>
</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">Volume: </span><span class="data_bold">
<value>29</value>
</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">Issue: </span><span class="data_bold">
<value>2</value>
</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">Pages: </span><span class="data_bold">
<value>26-152</value>
</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="label">Published: </span><span class="data_bold">
<value>JUN 1987</value>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, "html.parser")

items = soup.findAll('span', attrs = {'class': 'label' })
for item in items:
    label = item.contents[0]
    sibling = item.find_next_sibling('span')
    value = sibling.select('value')[0].text
    print (label, value )
```

Result:

```
Volume:  29
Issue:  2
Pages:  26-152
Published:  JUN 1987
```

I am far from clever enough to have written this without trying some possibilities that failed. Are you using something like IDLE that suggest alternatives and to try out snippets of code to see what results they give?

PS: When you come back to SO again please post HTML and other text as text (not as image files), so that answerers can use cut-and-paste.

Comment: Thank you Bill! I already changed the image for the code. I'm trying your code and I'm making some adjustments. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Beautifulsoup has its own regex functionality

```
html = '<html><span>Volume: </span><span class="data_bold"><value>20</value></span></html>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
matches = soup.findAll(text=re.compile('Volume'))
for match in matches:
    element = match.parent 
    #o/p: <span>Volume: </span>
    sibling_tag = element.findNextSibling()
    #o/p: <span class="data_bold"><value>20</value></span>
    print sibling_tag.find('value').text
    #o/p: u'20'
```

Note: This is just an example without having access to the actual html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I couldn't make it to work. However, this answer it is helpful for me for trying new solutions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it! I just wrote this:

```
numericValues= re.findall('<value>(.+?)</value>', str(soup))
```

This gave the followig output:

```
['100-121', '35', '1', '3-25', 'SPR 1993']
```

The first number I don't know what it was, but the next ones were the ones that I needed. Then I just iterate the values:

```
i = 0
while i < len(numericValues):
    columnVolume.append(numericValues[i+1])
    columnIssue.append(numericValues[i+2])
    columnPages.append(numericValues[i+3])
    columnDate.append(numericValues[i+4][-4:])
    i = i + 5
```

Thank you all for your help!